# White space not trimming in Pandas dataframe csv export

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a simple strip of all the white space in a column of my dataset, but when I export it out as a CSV, space is still there. Is there any reason that this would be occurring?

```
import pandas as pd

excel_path = "testfile.xlsx"

data = pd.read_excel(excel_path, usecols="B,D,E")
data["Name"].str.strip()

data.to_csv("your_new_csv.csv")
```

Here is an example of the kind of data that is in the xlsx file with column header "Name"

```
Immersion
    Internal Kick Off
    Client Kick Off
    Prepare Discussion Guides
    Stakeholder Interviews
    Distillation of Findings
    Theory of Change
    Impact Measurement Plan
```

I want the final file to be formatted as:

```
Immersion
Internal Kick Off
Client Kick Off
Prepare Discussion Guides
Stakeholder Interviews
Distillation of Findings
Theory of Change
Impact Measurement Plan
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) returns a new Series, it doesn't modify the column in place. So assign that back to the DataFrame column

```
data["Name"] = data["Name"].str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to update the original df? I still want to export a CSV file that contains the rest of the columns too!

Comment: `df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.strip()`